# Pin header connector

Tags: pcb, connector, wire

In my project I make use of 3 PWM I²C-boards, each having 3 x 16 pin connectors. My initial thought was to use jumper connectors to connect LEDs to the pins but they are not reliable enough.

I would rather not de-solder 144 (3*x*16*x*3) pins, Is there a connector that can securely connect to these pins?

**Wishlist:**

- If at all possible, no de-solder of existing pins on board.
- Secure connection (mild vibrations occasionally)
- 48/24/12/3-pin connector, all acceptable
- No pre-made connector wire. I want to be able to tailor-make the wire length
- Screw terminal is ok but not at all required
- Connector available to buy in Europe/Sweden

**my background:**

- beginner in electronics, hence the aversion to de-solder 144 pins. its gonna take me a year!
- beginner in electronics, so if the solution / connector is blatantly obvious, please have patience with me. I looked at TME and Mouse websites and there is literally a million different connectors available but I lack knowledge to find a fitting connector.

[image: PCA9685 board]

[image]

Comment: For what are you using the PWM outputs? To me it looks as if this board was designed with the option to control [RC servos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_%28radio_control%29), too. These servos commonly use 3-pin connectors. It may be a solution to use servo cables, which are available separately.

Comment: @thebusybee LEDs, both directly as in single LEDs (soldered connection), and push buttons that have LEDs built in (spade connector).

Comment: Please add new information to your question by [edit]ing it. Comments are not for this, this is not a forum. -- Did you try 1x20 connectors? The gaps look as if they are 1 and 2 steps wide.

Comment: @thebusybee  No, only single (1 female) jumper connectors

Comment: You forgot to tell us the pitch. Is it 2.54 mm?

Comment: @DavideAndrea According to the PCB drawing, yes.

Comment: @the busybee. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my [Select-a-conn - connector selection utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=unshrouded_plugs_2p54&s=AMPMODU%20Mod%20IV%203r%20plug), there is only one female plug out there that has 3 rows of sockets with a 0.1" pitch:

TE AMPMODU Mod IV such as part number 86308-1.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/86308-1/295279

https://www.te.com/usa-en/search.html?q=86308-1&source=header

[image: TE 86308-1]

{Digikey}

However, it's "available to order". I.e., it's not actually made unless someone orders 3200 of them.

The reason that they don't make 3-row unshrouded plugs is that it's impossible to reach the inner row to extract a socket.

Therefore, what I propose is to use [6-circuits 2.54 mm unshrouded plugs](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=unshrouded_plugs_2p54&&fl=000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000-100-%7C2.54%7C6%7C%7C%7C) turned 90 degrees. They must be perfectly prismatic and unkeyed, so that they do not interfere with each other when stacked side-by-side. (The Dubox that someone else proposed is not, so two side-by-side would interfere with each other.)

[image: Molex C-Grid III 90143]

{Molex C-Grid III 90143, Digikey}

This includes:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Harwin](https://www.harwin.com/connectors-hardware/pcb-connectors/2-54mm-pitch-pcb-connectors/) - M20 plug 2r - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/harwin-inc/M20-1070300/3727995)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/partSearch?query=90143&pQuery=) - C-Grid III 90143 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0901430006/760772)
- TE - AMPMODU Mod IV 2r plug - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/87456-1/29967)

Answer (score 1):

Something we occassionally use when we have pinheader we'd like to connect is a dubox connector.

[image]

The problem might be that you also need to have to right crimping tools what can be quite expensive for a one time use. Alternatively you can also buy the pre-crimped cables if available in your desired length.
If these connectors are secure enough is difficult to say, they might require a little drop of glue to sustain vibrations.